# Specify a DB column name as a static variable in the model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model class, in which I define the name of the column.

```
class Permission extends Model 
{
    public static $colName = 'mycolname';
    //...
}
```

In the controller:

```
//...
// Trying to get the value of column 'mycolname'
// I wanna do it this way, but I'm getting a syntax error:
$data = $user->permission->Permission::$colName;

// This way works, but I don't want to hardcode the column name here
$data = $user->permission->mycolname;
```

In case it's important, I'm using Laravel 5.3 / Eloquent.

Is this possible someway?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take variable name first, use like this

```
  $mycolname = Permission::colName;
```

And fetch variable like this.

```
  $data = $user->permission->$mycolname;
```

Comment: Works, thanks! Too bad it needs the local variable... would have been cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this : `Permission::colName`
and maybe this too but i didn't test it

```
$data = $user->permission::colName
```

Comment: The first `permission` is retrieving the associated `permission` table info, so this doesn't work.

Comment: you can save it in a variable then do this `$user->permission->$variable ;`

Answer (score 0):

> import Permission Model

```
$columnname = Permission::$colName; // Add this line to get column name

$data = $user->permission->$columnname; // get column value
```

Answer (score 0):

Although someone else already posted a solution to this (which I've accepted), I ended up creating a method in the model that does the logic for me there:

```
class Permission extends Model 
{
    public static $colName = 'mycolname';
    //...

    public static function canCreateStuff($id) {

        $perm = Permission::where('user_id', $id)->where(Permission::$colName, 1)->first();

        if ($perm != null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

In the controller:

```
//...
// Trying to get the value of column 'mycolname'
// I wanna do it this way, but I'm getting a syntax error:
$data = Permission::canCreateStuff($id);
```